# Delegate System.Func<dbPSRModel.tbProject,int,bool> does not take 1 arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, json

I'm trying to populate a modal using AJAX. This is the method that returns the data I hope to populate the modal with but I get a red line under `(x => x.tbProject == i)` and it says:

> Delegate System.Func does not take 1
>   arguments.

Any ideas?

```
public partial class view_requests : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    [WebMethod]
    public static string getProjectByID(int id)
    {
        using (dbPSREntities4 myEntities = new dbPSREntities4())
        {
            var thisProject = myEntities.tbProjects.Where(x => x.tbProject == i).ToList();

            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var json = serializer.Serialize(thisProject);

            return json;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm. It's not the error message I'd have expected, but I suspect the problem may be related to the fact that you're referring to `i` within the lambda expression - and that's a variable which doesn't exist. That may be causing the compiler to get confused about which overload you're trying to use.

Try using

```
.Where(x => x.tbProject == id)
```

instead. Having said that, it's also odd that if you're querying `myEntities.tbProjects` you need to use `x.tbProject`... it would help if you'd give more details about your `tbProjects` property and its type. (Following .NET naming conventions would be nice too.)